# Do computations on polygon require less computing power?

Tags: sidechain, plasma

My understanding of Ethereum, is that computing power is paid for in gas fees. I’m assuming a dapp like AAVE requires the same computing power to execute a transaction, regardless of what blockchain is being used. If not,  why not?  If so, why are people motivated to do the calculations on polygon if they make so much less money?

If that is not clear, I’m wondering why the same action can be so much cheaper on polygon mainnet than Ethereum mainnet.